# Compiling OpenCV 3.0.0 for Python 2.7.11 on Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, compilation, opencv3.0

I am trying to compile my own **opencv 3.0.0** from source for **Python 2.7.11**. I find this messages. These messages appear in `CMAKE`.

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", but required is at least "3.4" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", but required is at least "3.2" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
```

[image: cmake]

And after I made the compile the first time I didn't find the Python directory that should include `cv2.pyd`.

Also I get this error messsage when I check the opencv_dnn_BUILD_TORCH_IMPORTER.

```
CMake Error at C:/opencv3/sources/opencv_contrib/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:57 (message):
  OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH environment variable was not specified
```

[image: cmake error]

Can I find any source that has the steps of compiling `opencv` for `Python 2.7.x` on a `Windows machine`

Answer (score 0):

By trying to install OpenCV from source on a Windows machine you are taking on a very large task. I would strongly recommend installing from the prebuilt packages available from OpenCV's website - and I'm also recommend going straight for OpenCV 3.1 rather than 3.0. You can get that install file here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0/opencv-3.1.0.exe/download

With that said, if you still want to install from source you can get all the instructions to do this in Windows here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

*Good luck, and happy coding!*

Comment: I found the reference that is concerned with the installation from source. It's very bad. Regarding your are saying that I install it with prebuilt libraries. I want to do this as it's much easier as you say, but, I have to use SIFT and SURF for some projects. So I am obligated to compile it from source.